# Why does this while loop only run once?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm having issues with all of my loops only running one time through and then quitting out and I'm very confused. Here's an example of the while loop that only runs once:

```
public String getAstWhile(int ast)  { 
    int s = 0;
    int n = ast;
    while (s < n)
    {
        s++;
        return "*";

    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement inside your `while`.How would you expect to run more than once? Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using the `return` keyword which signals Java to exit the method.